# Observing .effectiveAppearance change from appDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

In my appDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, I would like to observe the appearance change from light / dark mode.

Neither of these seems to do the trick:

```
NSApp.observe(\.effectiveAppearance) { _, _ in
    print("it works!")
}

NSApplication.shared.observe(\.effectiveAppearance) { _, _ in
    print("it works!")
}
```

How would I detect this change?

Comment: Do you keep a strong reference to the `NSKeyValueObservation` object?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep this `observer` alive by assigning it to a class level object as below,

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


    private var observer: Any!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        self.observer = NSApp.observe(\.effectiveAppearance) { _, _ in
            print("it works!")
        }
    }
}
```